# Move Image translation using android animation

Tags: android

I need an animation for an image in my application. where two balls size images should coming from the right and left corner and move all over the screen infinity on click of button

please help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a [TranslateAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

TranslateAnimation allows you to create a simple animation from one (x,y) position to another (x,y) position.

If you wanted it to run infinitely, you might do something like this:

```
    TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,100,100);
    translateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
    translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            /* Set new from values, then generate new to values here, then restart animation */
        }
    });

    View myView = new View();
    myView.startAnimation( translateAnimation);
```

In my `onAnimationRepeat` method, I would reset the fromX and fromY values of the animation, and generate new toX and toY values, then start it over again.

This will only move the view from one point to another, if you need it to do multiple different animations at once, you might need to create a custom animation.